# Nginx 500 internal error with worker connection are not enough

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server, nginx-config

I searched over different questions on stackoverflow and googling but still cannot solve the problem.

The flow of my structure is xx.domain.com which is pointing to server ip address 11.11.xx.xx. I have setup SSL for the subdomain to listen on port 8443. Here are nginx conf.

```
    server {
    listen 8443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:8443 ssl default_server;
    server_name xx.domain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xx.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xx.domain.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8443;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            }}
```

Here is the error log

```
*763 768 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: xx.domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:8443/", host: "xx.domain.com"
```

I use Golang with Nginx. Please help

**Update**

After increasing 'worker_connection' to 2048 as suggested by Voraprung in the comments, the 500 error still there with following error log.

```
*2022 socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: xx.domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://127.0.0.1:8443/", host: "xx.domain.com"
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Go or programming. Try ServerFault.

Comment: add ``worker_connections 2048;`` to your config, restart nginx and see what happens.  That's what I'd do

Comment: @Vorsprung I have changed the number as suggest. It doesn't work. Please see the error log updated in the post. Now it change to "too many open files"

Comment: the problem is now a linux kernel limit, see https://easyengine.io/tutorials/linux/increase-open-files-limit/

Comment: @Vorsprung I have increased the limits by following the links. I got another error "110: Connection Timeout". So I follow this link https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/upstream-timed-out/ to increase the timeout time. The timeout error still exist with additional error "worker process exited on signal 9"